# Rails SELECT Distinct with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

So I am trying to use the SELECT Distinct option on my table

`Hashlog.select("DISTINCT tag").select("created_at").order("created_at DESC").limit(10)`

```
 1.9.3-p286 :017 > Hashlog.select("DISTINCT tag").select("created_at").order("created_at DESC").limit(10)
      Hashlog Load (0.7ms)  SELECT DISTINCT tag, created_at FROM "hashlogs" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
     => [#<Hashlog tag: "new", created_at: "2012-12-11 04:06:37">, 
     #<Hashlog tag: "now", created_at: "2012-12-11 04:06:33">, 
     #<Hashlog tag: "googleold", created_at: "2012-12-11 04:06:28">, 
     #<Hashlog tag: "google", created_at: "2012-12-11 04:06:26">, 
     #<Hashlog tag: "facebook", created_at: "2012-12-11 04:06:21">, 
     #<Hashlog tag: "facebook", created_at: "2012-12-11 04:06:18">, 
     #<Hashlog tag: "faceboot", created_at: "2012-12-11 04:06:15">]
```

So I want the results to only unique on the tag column, but it will not let me order by created_at unless its passed through the select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is select distinct tag values ordered by the *earliest* (i.e. smallest) `created_at` for each tag. That would be one way to resolve the ambiguity resulting from a tag with multiple associated `created_at` values.

If that's the case, try something like the following:

```
Hashlog.select("tag, min(created_at) as earliest").group("tag").order("earliest DESC").limit(10)
```

.

Comment: Thats great, it worked perfectly.

But to go one further, could you explain as to why that worked, but the distinct did not?

Not really clear on the usage of group.

If not that's okay, I appreciate the answer

Comment: `DISTINCT` would have worked fine if you didn't need to sort by `created_at`. You always need to select a field whenever you want to order by it. `GROUP` works similarly to `DISTINCT` in that it picks out unique values from (a) column(s), but it also allows you to select and/or write conditions on their associated rows. In this case, we selected the minimum of `created_at` among all rows containing a given tag (which form a `GROUP` for that tag), called it `earliest`, and sorted the final set of tags by `earliest`. See [this](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this following snippet in my project

```
Product.select("DISTINCT(products.material_id), products.material_id, products.class_id").where('products.class_id' => current_user.class_id)
```